# Method names in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, methods

In Objective-C we have method names like `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, but in Swift the method for the same job looks different.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Is the name of this method simply `application` since everything else are just parameters? Or is it called `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` with a space in the name?
I was looking for an official answer in the Apple Documentation but I could not find one.

Comment: use `"application:"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method is indeed called `application`, however `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is an external parameter name and:

> If you provide an external parameter name for a parameter, that external name must always be used when you call the function.

Since there can be two functions called `application` with different external parameter names, we always have to specify the external parameters when referring to a function. So, the whole name of the function/method would be

```
application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)
```

<strike>You are right there hasn't be any convention made yet for referring to Swift functions. The safest way to refer to a function now is to use the Obj-C convention.</strike>

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

Which is still used in all Apple documentation links.

This convention is used throughout Apple documentation.

Comment: This is the best answer and covers all concerns and interesting points (except the documentation does explicitly refer to them via the Objective-C version): http://i.imgur.com/QVcdcRB.png (there's a little box at the top of the documentation to choose "Objective-C", "Swift", or "Both".  If you put it on Swift, the Swift style shows up like this.

Answer (score 1):

The method is indeed “just” `application`.
Swift uses this more often, if you have a `tableview` for example almost all functions start with `tableview`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {}
```

The parameters “define” the functions instead of the method.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, its name in the documentation? it is `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` I can’t imagine circumstances when you need to call it manually but just in case:

```
    application(app, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:aDictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Naming is exactly the same in both languages.

If you want a good proof, try using any other naming in a selector.

Comment: While this answer makes a good point, it could certainly do a much better job of explaining its point.